# Add an on change listener to bootstrap 4 button group?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I have this (bootstrap 4) button group as follows:

```
<div id="timeselector" class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-secondary active ">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="sec" autocomplete="off" checked>Second
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-secondary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="min" autocomplete="off">Minute
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-secondary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="hr" autocomplete="off">Hour
  </label>
</div>
```

I want to add a JS onchange listener and find out which one was pressed (e.g. Second, Minute, or Hour). I don't want to add a listener to each button because there are a lot of buttons like these on my page.

I've tried adding something like this:

```
$('#timeselector').on("change", function() {
    alert(this)
});
```

But that doesn't work. If I change "change" to "click", it does alert, but it doesn't give me which was selected.

Can someone help with this? Thank you!

Comment: You're targeting the div, which won't react to the change. Try targeting the inputs specifically with`$('#timeselector input')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `click` instead an to attach the event to the `input`'s inside your div :

```
$('#timeselector input')
```

```js
$('#timeselector input').on("click", function() {
  alert(this.id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div id="timeselector" class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-secondary active ">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="sec" autocomplete="off" checked>Second
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-secondary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="min" autocomplete="off">Minute
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-secondary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="hr" autocomplete="off">Hour
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: any idea as to why `change` didn't work for the example in the OP? Both `click` and `change` work for me.

Comment: The change must be attached to the radio inputs, the OP code attach it to the div, that why it's not working...